# Azure CDN session issue backend application gateway

Tags: azure, jira, azure-cdn

I have setup jira with CDN (premium Verzion) and application gateway. All request serve from CDN. I have identify the actual issue. Issue was Application gateway consider CDN ip as client ip, So each request AG providing different cookie token. I need Rule engine for forwarding client ip only to AG.

Clietn -> CDN -> Application Gateway -> Jira node

Answer (score 0):

You should have an option to indicate **Verizon** to add a header with the client's **IP Address**. Take a look at [Verizon-specific HTTP headers for Azure CDN rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-http-headers), specifically, on the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that option. but application gateway providing different cookie. I tried to connect the application gateway directly and all cookies comes under "request cookie" and its working without issues. But when I connect via CDN, application gateway cookies are getting set in "response cookie" (Think so application gateway considers each request from CDN as client IP's after including x-forwarded-for). Still issue not fixed